# Set Organization and Class Prefix with Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoa, prefix, workspace, organization

I have a project using CocoaPods. One of the used pods is a devpod.
Because it's sometimes just easy to do I create a new file right inside the devpod of the pod project in my workspace and run pod install directly after that.
Sadly the pod project has no organization and class prefix set, so that the head of each file is missing the copyright line. I always need to add that myself.
I can set organization and class prefix for the pod project and it works, but as soon as pod install is run again those settings vanish.

Is there a way to configure with a podfile to set the oranization and class prefix for the pod project in my workspace so I don't need to do it manually each time (and forget that most of the time)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append this to your Podfile and you should be ready to go.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.root_object.attributes["CLASSPREFIX"] = "ABC"
    installer.pods_project.root_object.attributes["ORGANIZATIONNAME"] = "my company"
end
```

Comment: Good! BTW, Is there any way to modify project name instead of "Pods".