# IDETemplateMacros.plist not working when developing Library

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13, xcode-template

I have created a IDETemplateMacros.plist with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>FILEHEADER</key>
    <string> ___COPYRIGHT___</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have placed this at `/Users/<User>/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IDETemplateMacros.plist`. This works well for xcode projects that I run/build from a `.xcodeproj`.

Unfortunately, I also work on a library which doesn't have an associated `.xcodeproj` and is only built and tested but never compiled. When I create new files in that project, it seems like xcode recognizes that it shouldn't use the standard header -- but instead of using the above, it only includes at the top an empty comment line:

```
//
```

Any thoughts on how to get this macro working in developing libraries locally which don't have `.xcodeproj`'s associated to them?

Running
Xcode 13.1

Comment: Just ran into this myself, did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue, I've figured out the problem, at least when using CocoaPods.

The problem is that `___COPYRIGHT___` isn't set on the pods, so after a bit of googling I found this:
[Set Organization and Class Prefix with Podfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760150/set-organization-and-class-prefix-with-podfile)

So the fix for me was to add this to my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.root_object.attributes["ORGANIZATIONNAME"] = "My Company Name"
end
```

Obviously you need to replace "My Company Name" with your actual company name.

Hope this helps.